# Does the naming convention for ENUMs in C# usually have everything in UPPERCASE?

Tags: c#, enums

Here's my ENUM:

```
public enum ATI
{
    Two = 0,
    Three = 1,
    Five = 2,
}
```

I realize there are no strict conventions but normally would the files Two,Three and Five be in uppercase?

Comment: I think that you mixing up with a  `const`

Comment: It should be camel casing, but in the end it's a user preference or coding convention.

Comment: Thanks, is there a common convention that people use when naming an enum such as starting with "e" or anything like that?

Comment: All-uppercase is a C language convention.  A language that puts enum members in the global namespace.  Very awkward, you have to come up with good names to avoid identifier collisions.  Using all-uppercase helps with that, a short prefix is another way.  C++ had this problem too, but fixed it with enum class in C++11.  C# does not have and never had that problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

One should use Pascal case when they are typing enum types and values.  This looks like

```
public enum Ati
{
    Two = 0,
    Three = 1,
    Five = 2,
}
```

According to Microsoft:

```
   Identifier      |   Case    |   Example
--------------------------------------------
Enumeration type   |  Pascal   |  ErrorLevel      
Enumeration values |  Pascal   |  FatalError
```

The only thing that you should make all caps like that are constant/final variables.

When you have local variables you should always use camel case.

```
thisIsCamelCasedVariable = "ya baby";
```

More about enums: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(v=vs.71).aspx

More about naming conventions C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 25):

As already pointed out by [Jamins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47736038/5893316):
In C# enumerations and their values should be named in **PascalCasing**

When you defining a 'simple' enum, for example just for enumerating *the seasons of the year*, you should use the **singular**, like:

```
public enum SeasonOfTheYear
{
    Spring = 0,
    Summer = 1,
    Autumn = 2,
    Winter = 3
}
```

If you want to define a so called 'flag enum', for example to define *file permissions*. You should use the **plural**, like:

```
[Flags]
public enum FilePermissions
{
    None = 0,
    X = 1,
    W = 2,
    R = 4
}
```

---

More **Do and Don't**s from [.NET Design-Guidelines - Names Of Classes, Structs and Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces#naming-enumerations):

> **Naming Enumerations**
>
> Names of enumeration types (also called enums) in general should follow the standard type-naming rules (PascalCasing, etc.). However, there are additional guidelines that apply specifically to enums.
>
> ✓ DO use a singular type name for an enumeration unless its values are bit fields.
>
> ✓ DO use a plural type name for an enumeration with bit fields as values, also called flags enum.
>
> X DO NOT use an "Enum" suffix in enum type names.
>
> X DO NOT use "Flag" or "Flags" suffixes in enum type names.
>
> X DO NOT use a prefix on enumeration value names (e.g., "ad" for ADO enums, "rtf" for rich text enums, etc.).

---

*For more information: [C# Reference - Enumeration types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)*

---

*But these are just naming conventions and no laws. So not everyone sticks to it. So I suggest,  within a project team or company you should commit yourself to a uniform naming convention. But you should not only define it, you also have to communicate it, so that it is clear to all developers.*

Comment: Take an enum that is a subclass (e.g. RowState) of a class (e.g.RowModel). This is usefull because it provides a nice namespace that helps reducing the complexity of names: in the example, I have a class RowModel with its own possible states that are gathered in its own RowState enum; I could have a different class AnotherRowModel with its own RowState enum. Unfortunately this way I can't have a property with same name RowSate because that would be a duplicate member name. That's why enum suffix is useful.IMHO public RowStateEnum RowState {get;} is preferrable than public RowState State {get;}